# Is there a bug with the acceptance rate calculation?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, account

Just spotted [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/352512/cant-ping-remote-into-vpn-server-but-vpn-works), where the user currently has a displayed 57% acceptance rate. I had a look at profile for the user, and found that he'd asked 10 questions, and accepted 4 answers, which by my reckoning is an acceptance rate of 40%.

I'm guessing I'm likely missing something? I did wonder if the rate was calculated across all the SE sites, but I see many users (including this one - and myself) with different acceptance rates across different SE sites.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Questions without answers don't count against your acceptance rate.

It would be unfair to penalize someone for not accepting something that doesn't exist.

This my also apply if all the answers are negative, but I'm speculating.

Comment: this 4/(10-3)=~.57

Comment: I knew I must have been missing something. Pretty obvious now you mention it though, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

First, the accept rate is heavily cached.  Second, it excludes questions that are new (less then two days old), have no answers, or are community wiki.

- 10 questions
- 7 questions have answers.
- 4 are marked as accepted.

4/7 = 57.14%

Comment: "Heavily cached" means a user gets chastised for having 0%, who then goes through and accepts a bunch of answers will *still* have 0% for some time afterwards.